# USB 1.0 hub connected to usb 2.0 port not recognised

Tags: windows, usb

I have an old USB hub which works in my old notebook that probably only has 1.0 USB ports.

My new computer, which is a Duo Core 2.4, it always shows 'unknown device' when connected.

Is there a way to make it work in my new computer, which probably has USB 2.0 ports?